# How to get changes in listview item to arraylist item behind it

Tags: android, listview, binding, listviewitem

I need a dynamic list of heterogeneous items with editable fields. Seems a bit complicated, but essentially user can add/remove items; each item can be of different type (I have an abstract class named `Action`, each single type extends it), and has editable fields (ie. EditText).

I used a `ListView` (it seemed the more natural way to do it), I did an adapter, extending `ArrayAdapter`, binded to an `ArrayList<Action>`, but I noticed that changes to list items are not backed to corresponding item of ArrayList.

It's hard to explain, but I do this:

Launch application, add an element of a certain type, write something on an EditText with id `R.id.action_add_text`, then I expected

```
String text = ((EditText) actions.get(0).view.findViewById(R.id.action_add_text)).getText().toString();
```

to be reflecting what I wrote in that EditText but it remains empty.

Where am I wrong? I need to get the current list state to save it, but I don't know where to retrieve it, is there a way to bind "bidirectionally" so that UI changes are reported back to adapter? Or should I iterate through listview children (but then what is the function of the adapter)?

Please be patient, I searched a lot but can't find nothing helpful (maybe I can't find the right words to search for)

Edit: ArrayAdapter implementation
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Action> {
    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<Action> actions = null;

    public ActionAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Action> actions) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, actions);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ActionHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(actions.get(position).viewId, parent, false);

            holder = new ActionHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.action_title);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ActionHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Action action = actions.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(action.title);

        return row;

    }

    static class ActionHolder
    {
        TextView title;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile I think I need to override getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount, right?

Comment: make ui changes and call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.

Comment: Add here implementation of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: @Raghunandan is notifyDataSetChanged() bidirectional? but also if it is, at that point how can I know when ui changed? By the way I'll watch the video, thank you.

Comment: @Raghunandan I watched the whole video, I have to say that's a concentrate of knowledge, thank you for this. And, at something like 47:00, it talks about complexity of a listview. This made me think that I underestimated the use of this view. Despite with this video and [this](http://commonsware.com/Android/Android_3-6-CC.pdf) (just discovered) now I should be able to figure out the fix needed to adapter etc, in fact I think that I can easily put all in a linear layout inside a scrollview, given that there will be few items (not more than 10, max 20 at a time?). Sorry for long reply

Answer (score 0):

The answer came up watching youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 :

While it's possible to do such a complex list (heterogeneous, dynamic list with *non-static* items, *non-static* in the sense of not readonly items like textviews), in this case it's better to avoid use of listview. They are much expensive and complex.

In cases of a small data set and a bunch of special cases, just like what I'm facing, it's a lot simpler to put a linearlayout inside a scrollview, and programmatically populate it.